# Karma unit test controller becomes undefined after adding resolver in ui-router

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-runner, angular-ui-router, resolver

1. In the configure.js:

   ```
   $stateProvider.state('home', {
       url: '/',
           views: {
               'nav-menu': {
                   templateUrl: '/views/nav-menu.ng',
                   controller: 'myApp.NavMenuController',
                   controllerAs: 'ctrl',
                   resolve: myApp.NavMenuController.resolve
               }
           }
       }
   });
   ```
2. In the controller.js:

   ```
   myApp.NavMenuController.resolve = {
       person: function($q) {
           return $q.defer().promise;
       }
   };
   ```

Error Message:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined

Comment: The error is saying `myApp.NavMenuController` is undefined. You're trying to reference this function somewhere w/out having an actual reference to the controller. Put the function on a service that you can inject into the configure function.

Comment: But it only fails for unit test. The resolver works fine in the real app.